# Amazon Redshift SQL Count Windows Function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]I am looking to get a rolling count of customers based on their loyalty tier. each tier is based on an LTV (0-124.99, 125-198.99, 199-749.99 and 750+). This is what I have right now which is just returning 0's for each date with a few 1's scattered throughout the years. Can anyone help with the windows function?

```
    SELECT TRUNC(CD.date) AS "day", tier, 
    COUNT(customer_email) OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(CD.date), tier ORDER BY 
    TRUNC(CD.date), tier 
    ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS "customers"
    FROM {{ @public_fact_criquet_loyalty_master AS LM}}
    RIGHT JOIN public.dim_calendar_dates CD ON TRUNC(CD.date) = TRUNC(LM.timestamp)
    WHERE TRUNC(CD.date) BETWEEN '2011-11-09' AND CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY TRUNC(CD.date), tier, customer_email
    ORDER BY TRUNC(CD.date), tier ASC
```

Comment: A golden rule is to avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Thanks Stu. This data is simply showing that I wasn't able to get the windows function to actually product correct results as noted in my question not to provide actually data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has changed to one about how to prep the data for analysis so I'm adding this code for the creation of the base data that can allow for further querying.

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (dt date, customer_email varchar(64), tier varchar(32));

insert into test values
('2/3/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '2almost_vip'),
('3/12/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '4the_players_club'),
('4/27/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '5the_players_club'),
('8/6/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '6the_players_club'),
('11/22/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '7the_players_club'),
('12/16/2021', 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com', '8the_players_club'),
('1/3/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '2almost_vip'),
('2/12/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '4the_players_club'),
('3/27/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '5the_players_club'),
('7/6/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '6the_players_club'),
('10/22/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '7the_players_club'),
('11/16/2021', 'abc@qrs.com', '8the_players_club');

with recursive dates(d) as (
select '2021-01-01'::date as d
union all
select d + 1 as d
from dates 
where d < '2021-12-31')  -- This CTE creates dates from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31)
select dt, customer_email, 
    LAG(min(tier), 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY dt ASC) AS tier -- Find the previous non-NULL tier - remember that group by runs before window
from (
    select dt, customer_email, tier as tier  -- combine your input data with ...
    from test
    union all
    select d as dt, customer_email, null as tier -- a list of all dates per email
    from dates 
    cross join (select DISTINCT customer_email from test)  -- combine all dates with all emails
    )
group by customer_email, dt
order by customer_email, dt;
```

The output of this query (based on the dummy data I entered) is a list of all dates for all email with their tier filled in.  What next steps you plan on doing is not clear to me so I'll leave it here.  Since this process is producing significantly more data than what it started with it is not going to be super efficient and there's a good chance that all the data isn't needed for the end result.  If this data expansion can be eliminated the processing speed should improve.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Due to the high amount of data I'll use this as a definitions table then call it to just count the count of unique records in each tier each day. Thank you much!

Comment: Good to hear and all the best

Answer (score 0):

You have partitioned by TRUNC(CD.date) which breaks up the count groups in a way I think you don't want.  Are you looking for this?

```
COUNT(customer_email) OVER(PARTITION BY tier ORDER BY day ASC 
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS "customers"
```

PS. You can use "day" in the window function as it has been defined as "TRUNC(CD.date)" in the first result column.

Comment: Thank you Bill that is all really helpful information. That did improve my results but still not quite what I was looking for. So it's adding one each day instead of actually counting the customers who are in that specific tier.

Comment: This is where some sample / test data and expected results would help clarify what you are desiring.  Are you looking for just count() and not a rolling count? 
 Window functions don't reduce the number of rows like group by does.  One thing to remember is that when you mix window functions and group by in the same level of a query that the group by runs first, then the window functions.  If you are expecting that the group by would run across the window results you will need a second level of query.

Comment: It's kind of hard to give simple data. I think at least explaining it may make more sense. So we have these 4 loyalty tiers that customers reach but hitting a certain LTV threshold. If they buy $130 on 1/20/21 and  another $85 on 9/13/21 they would be 2almost_vip from 1/20/21 - 9/12/21 then 3vip from 9/13 until their next purchase. I would to count how many people are in each tier on a daily basis.

Comment: So is this just "select ... , count(customer_email) ... group by day, tier"?  I suspect you may need more than this but could be the starting point

Comment: Yea that as the starting point. I have the date of when the entered the new tier but not that at the daily level. In the example above I only have 1/20/21 as the 2almost_vip level and all of the days in-between there and when they reach 3vip on 9/21/21. What I'm looking to accomplish is to 1) get the tier on every date and 2) get the count of each customer in each tier on each day

Comment: #1 - LAG() IGNORE NULLS OVER ... could be a way to fill in the tier in from previous rows as long as the empty tier values are NULL.  #2 - Should just be a SUM() and GROUP BY at this point.

Comment: SELECT TRUNC(CD.date) AS "day", customer_email, tier, 
  LAG(tier, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY TRUNC(CD.date) DESC) AS "previous_day_tier"
FROM {{ @loyalty_master AS LM}}
RIGHT JOIN public.dim_calendar_dates CD ON TRUNC(CD.date) = TRUNC(LM.timestamp)
WHERE TRUNC(CD.date) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE
  AND customer_email = 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyy.com'
GROUP BY TRUNC(CD.date), customer_email, tier
ORDER BY TRUNC(CD.date), customer_email, tier DESC

Comment: This is the code that I used and I'm getting just the order dates from that customer in loyalty_master and not all dates in that range from CD calendar dates

Comment: I don't see your data so this is confusing to figure out but let me try.  It sounds like you want to "copy" the tier value to all "later" dates.  I'd expect that "later" would translate into "ORDER BY TRUNC(CD.date) ASC", not DESC.  Next you will want the first row in the partition to have the tier value so that needs to be in your ORDER BY as well "ORDER BY TRUNC(CD.date) ASC, tier ASC" (assuming you have NULLs sorted last).  This is what I see from just looking at the code - seeing data and intermediate results would really help.

Comment: Results can be fund here - https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlDKnuv4BzX7gjmvI6Lsbik69IZK?e=00CCxl. ASC did fix one issue so thank you very much for that but it still doesn't show all dates between orders

Comment: So it looks like you aren't getting a value from lag() on the first row which makes sense.  There is no earlier row in the partition so it will return NULL.  If you want to just make this default to tier in this case you could just wrap it in an NVL().

Comment: So is there no way to get the tier on 2/20/21 which is a date between order dates?

Comment: I don't see info for 2/20/21 in either screen grab.  I'm guessing this is about getting the previous_day_tier when this needs to be gained from the data outside of your WHERE clause.  Help me out if I'm wrong but assuming I'm on track - to solve this you need the LAG() function to operate on data outside the date span in the WHERE clause.  I think the easiest way to do this is to change the one WHERE clause that says "TRUNC(CD.date) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE" to a HAVING clause.  WHERE filters the data going into the query, HAVING filters the data coming out.

Comment: This will mean that potentially a lot more data is being process and a slower query.  If you know that the tier data will will come no more than X days before the earliest date in the query output then you can add a WHERE clause with this wider time frame.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining this well. The 9 dates in the data I shared are the 9 ordered dates. I want to be able to see what tier a customer is in on every day regardless of if they purchased or not.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You need to replicate rows for all the dates in between.  So how big is your data?  I ask because there are simple ways to do this that tend to blow up on very large tables and a smart way.  Simple: cross join with your dates table and add a WHERE clause for the date range for this table as well.  You will also need to replicate rows only for dates after the tier date and before the next tier date.  Not hard but takes a bit of preconditioning on your data.  I can help with this if you like but let me address the smart way first...

Comment: If you data is large cross joining will just makes things very slow and there is a better way.   I wrote a white paper on this technique so I'll just point you there - http://wad-design.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sql_limits_wp.html  Again, I can answer question with this approach if needed.  I consult with companies to deliver high performance queries and redshift optimizations if that is of interest to you.

Comment: We only have about 150,000 customers so making that many customers have a row for each date may cause it to be a bigger query. Would love some help on the preconditioning of my data

Comment: Adding another answer as this has morphed quite a bit